# How to read line-by-line in a file on remote machine

Tags: ansible

first line:  `/u01/app/oracle/oradata/TEST/`

second line: `/u02/`

How to read both lines in a same variable and by using same varible i want know the present working directory through shell commands in ansible

Comment: please can you explain the following a little better. I do no understand what it is you are tying to do.
> How to read both lines in a same variable and by using same varible i want know the present working directory through shell commands in ansible

Comment: @Raghu: Welcome! Follow [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MattSeymour Actually i posted two line . That is in a file. I want read every line into a variable. How it is ?

Answer (score 1):

The task below creates the list of the lines from a file

```
- set_fact:
    lines_list: "{{ lines_list|default([]) + [item] }}"
  with_lines: cat /path/to/file
```

It's possible to create both a list

```
"lines_list": [
    "/u01/app/oracle/oradata/TEST/", 
    "/u02/"
]
```

and a dictionary

```
"lines_dict": {
    "0": "/u01/app/oracle/oradata/TEST/", 
    "1": "/u02/"
}
```

with the *combine* filter

```
- set_fact:
    lines_dict: "{{ lines_dict|default({})|combine({idx: item}) }}"
  with_lines: cat /path/to/file
  loop_control:
    index_var: idx
```

---

"Present working directory through shell commands in ansible" can be printed from the registered variable. For example

```
- command: echo $PWD
  register: result
- debug:
    var: result.stdout
```

(not tested)

Comment: Thanks, but the content is in a file. Through the file i have to register line-by-line . That is my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use command to read a file from disk

```
  - name: Read a file into a variable
    command: cat /path/to/your/file
    register: my_variable
```

And then do something like below to loop over the lines in the file.

```
- debug: msg="line: {{ item }}"
  loop: y_variable.stdout_lines
```